# Backbone Marionette ItemView with Subviews best practice

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

I have `pages` with many `partials` in Backbone.

`page` is rendered with an ItemView, but the page has `partials`, which I render manually in a CollectionView..

Is their an appropriate way to add the CollectionView so that `.render` and `.close` are called automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have partials in your application the best way is to use [Marionette Layout](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.layout.md).
And when you `show` or `close` any region it renders and closes automatically.

```
var Layout = Backbone.Marionette.Layout.extend({
  mainRegion: "#main"
});

var layout = new Layout();
layout.mainRegion.show(new PartialView());
```